# Set foreground colour of Image's ToolTip

Tags: wpf

How do you set the Foreground colour for a single Image's ToolTip? (There are multiple Image controls on the page but I want to have the style applied to just one)

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

For the image that you want to set the foreground to, add the following xaml code:

```
<Image Name="image1" Source="Untitled.png">
        <Image.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Foreground="Red">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Submit Request</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Submits the request to the server.</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

The **Foreground="Red"** sets the color of the foreground for that specific tool tip.

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Red Foreground on Tooltip for one image]

**SOURCE:** http://wpftutorial.net/ToolTip.html